# Why is .params not working when used in this.props.match.params?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am following an online tutorial using an API and I think it has to do with the router I am using compared to the Tutorial's HashBrowser Router. But can anyone shed any light on why this isn't working?

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import PkmnList from './components/PkmnList'
import PkmnStats from './components/PkmnStats'

class App extends Component{

  render(){

    return (  
      <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="w-full h-full bg-platnium">
            <Navbar/>
          
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<PkmnList/>} />
                <Route exact path="/pokemon/:index"  element={<PkmnStats/>} />
              </Routes>
            
          </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )


  }
  
}
export default App;
```

**PkmnCard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import loading from './loading.gif'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export default class PkmnCard extends Component {

  state = {

    name:'',
    url: '',
    index:'',
    
  }
  componentDidMount () {

    const { name , url} = this.props;
    const index = url.split('/')[url.split('/').length - 2];
    const sprite =`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${index}.png`;

    this.setState({

      name,
      index,
      sprite
      

    })
    


  }
  render() {

    


    return (
      <Link to={`pokemon/${this.state.index}`}>
        <div className='flex flex-col h-64  items-center p-10 rounded-xl  shadow-lg hover:shadow-2xl hover:border-stone-700 bg-white select-none '>
            <h3 className=' text-center'>{this.state.name.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(letter => letter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + letter.substring(1)).join(' ')}</h3>
            <h1>{this.state.url}</h1>
            {this.state.imageLoading ? (<img src={loading} className="mx-auto w-10 h-10" alt="loading gif"/>) :null}
            <img className='mx-auto' style={this.state.tooManyRequests ? {display: "none"} : this.state.imageLoading ? null : {display: "block"}} src={this.state.sprite} alt={this.state.name} onLoad={() => this.setState({imageLoading: false})} onError={ () => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: true})} />
            {this.state.tooManyRequests ? (<h6 className='mx-auto bg-red-600'> <span className='text-white'>Too Many Requests </span></h6>) :null }
            <h3 className="text-center">-No.{this.state.index}-</h3>
          
        </div>
      </Link>

    )   

  }
  
}
```

**PkmnStats.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class PkmnStats extends Component {

    state = {
        name:'',
        index:'',
        imageUrl:''
    };
    
    async componentDidMount(){
    
        const {index} = this.props.match.params;

        const pkmnUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${index}/`
        //const pkmnSpecies = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${index}/`

        const pkmnResponse = await axios.get(pkmnUrl);
        const name = pkmnResponse.data.name;
        this.setState({ name });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
               <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I read to use `useParams()` but I cant use that with a function call right? Im confused and stuck as how to solve this. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems working with class' states and sometimes problems came from the definition of the class state and how the props are passed to the child. Maybe try to add a constructor with `super(props)` at the top level of your class.

```
  //State setup
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={
      // Your setup
    }
  }
```